# How to get string array from xml to fragment's java file?

Tags: java, android

Below code shows null pointer exception..

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

private String[] eArray = getActivity()
                              .getResources()
                              .getStringArray(R.array.English);
```

What are the other options, searching in stackoverflow did not give me success..
I am using FragmentPagerAdapter also.. which is not related to this eArray.. but it contains data for images.

Comment: getActivity() is null. You need to assign eArray at a point in your fragment's life-cycle when it is attached to an activity. onCreate would be a fine place to start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) is returning null because you are using it before fragment get attached to Activity.*

You need to initialize this at `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    eArray = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.English);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. So, for fragment, we need to initialize at onCreateView

Comment: and for activity, is it ok to define globally ?

Comment: you can not initialize it as globally, but you can declare it.